# Python - Using Strings As A Condition Operator In An If Statements

Tags: python, if-statement

In Python is it possible to use a string as an operator in an if statement condition?

I would like to have an object with two values and an operator to test them.
For Example:

```
class Condition:
    def __init__(self, value1, operator, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.operator = operator
        self.value2 = value2

    def test(self):
        if self.value1 self.operator self.value2: <- THIS IS NOT CORRECT.
            return True
        else:
            return False

condition = Condition(5, ">", 4)
if condition.test() == True:
    print("passed")
else:
    print("failed")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module provides functions corresponding to all the built-in operators, so you can write:

```
import operator

class Condition:
    def __init__(self, value1, op, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.op = op
        self.value2 = value2
    def test(self):
        return self.op(self.value1, self.value2)

condition = Condition(5, operator.gt, 4)

if condition.test():
    print("passed")
else:
    print("failed")
```

If you want to pass strings instead of the functions, you can use a `dict` to map them:

```
import operator

OPERATOR_SYMBOLS = {
    '<': operator.lt,
    '<=': operator.le,
    '==': operator.eq,
    '!=': operator.ne,
    '>': operator.gt,
    '>=': operator.ge
}

class Condition:
    def __init__(self, value1, op, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.op = op
        self.value2 = value2
    def test(self):
        return OPERATOR_SYMBOLS[self.op](self.value1, self.value2)

condition = Condition(5, '>', 4)

if condition.test():
    print("passed")
else:
    print("failed")
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval('{}{}{}'.format(v1,op,v2))`

Comment: [this is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: I am going to use what @dan04 suggested but I will keep this in mind if I ever need it in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[The `operator` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) provides the various comparators as functions, so you could map from string form to a function to perform the comparison:

```
import operator

class Condition:

    cmp_to_op = {'==': operator.eq,
                  '!=': operator.ne,
                  '<': `operator.lt,
                  '<=': `operator.le,
                  '>': `operator.gt,
                  '>=': `operator.ge}

    def __init__(self, value1, operator, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.operator = self.cmp_to_op(operator)
        self.value2 = value2

    def test(self):
        # No need for if return True else return False; comparison already returns
        # True or False for normal objects
        return self.operator(self.value1, self.value2)
```